# How do I rebuild a gridLayout during resize?

Tags: resize, pyqt, rebuild, qgridlayout

I am trying to catch resize event of the window, and when I do, basically delete all the widget items in a gridLayout and rebuild the rows/columns to fit the new resized window.  I am having trouble getting this to work properly and not sure if this is the best method that I have used.  Right now two issues happen:

1. It doesn't seem to be deleting items, rebuilding and adding the columns properly as I resize the window bigger (some items delete, some get added, but seem to just overlap and never fit to the new window size).
2. Resize seems to get called on start/creation of the window.

```
class Window (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.thumbs = []
        self.thumbWidgets = []

        self._resize_timer = None
        self.resizeCompleted.connect(self.handleResizeCompleted)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        self.home()

    def home(self):

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)

        '''MainLAYOUT
        '''
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.thumb_tab_QGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)

        '''GroupBoxLAYOUT
        '''
        self.vLayout =  QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.thumb_tab_QGroupBox)
        self.vLayout.setObjectName("GroupVLayout")


        #Scroll Area
        self.thumbScrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self.thumb_tab_QGroupBox)
        self.thumbScrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.thumbScrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.thumbScrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.thumbScrollArea.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.thumbScrollArea.setObjectName("thumb_scrollArea")

        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(840, scrollAreaX))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.thumbScrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.thumbScrollArea)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.thumb_tab_QGroupBox)

        #Grid in Scroll Area
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout_QGridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout_QGridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        #Loads thumbnails
        self.getThumbnails()

        self.mainLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def resizeEvent(self, resizeEvent):
        self.updateResizeTimer(300)

    def updateResizeTimer(self, interval=None):
        if self._resize_timer is not None:
            self.killTimer(self._resize_timer)
        if interval is not None:
            self._resize_timer = self.startTimer(interval)
        else:
            self._resize_timer = None

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        if event.timerId() == self._resize_timer:
            self.updateResizeTimer()
            self.resizeCompleted.emit()

    def handleResizeCompleted(self):
        print('resize complete')

        # Get new window size on resize
        width = self.centralwidget.frameGeometry().width()
        height = self.centralwidget.frameGeometry().height()

        thumbsPerRow = width / 200
        print "numThumbnails per Width", thumbsPerRow

        self.gridLayoutWidget.adjustSize()
        self.gridLayout_QGridLayout.maximumSize()

        for widget in self.thumbWidgets:
            print "Removing widget", widget
            self.gridLayout_QGridLayout.removeWidget(widget)
            #widget.deleteLater()

        self.populate(self.thumbWidgets, QtCore.QSize(200,200), thumbsPerRow)

    def queryThumbnailCount(self):
        ....
        ...
        ..
        return sizeX

    def getThumbnails(self):
        .....
        ....
        ...
        .
        self.createThumbWidgets(self.thumbs, QtCore.QSize(200,200))
        self.populate(self.thumbs, QtCore.QSize(200,200))

    def createThumbWidgets(self, pics, size, imagesPerRow=4, flags=QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding):
        for pic in pics:           
            label = QtGui.QLabel("")
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(pic)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(size, flags)
            label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.thumbWidgets.append(label)


    #Add thumbnails to grid
    def populate(self, pics, size, imagesPerRow=6, flags=QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding):
        row = col = 0
        for widget in self.thumbWidgets:          
            print "Adding Image to column "+str(col)
            self.gridLayout_QGridLayout.addWidget(widget, row, col)
            col +=1
            if col % imagesPerRow == 0:
                row += 1
                col = 0        


GUI = Window()
GUI.show()
```

Comment: I did something similar [here](https://bitbucket.org/labscript_suite/labscript_utils/src/8f4c1bea806fdf3fb722ed2adcd69881ff9845b8/qtwidgets/toolpalette.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#toolpalette.py-228). Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Also, this seems eerily similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36156360/1994235) question that was posted a few hours after yours. Is this a homework problem?

Comment: That is quite funny... no, not a homework assignment.  This is something for work.  But odd that someone has the same issue I am having.  I will try to look at your suggestion... is there a particular section of it that relates to rebuilding the grid?  It seems rather lengthy.

Comment: Lines 293-307 are the most relevant in my example. In short, you don't need to delete the widgets and recreate them. Just remove them from the layout and then re-add them in with a different number per row. My code isn't that lengthy if you remove all the comments and only look at the `ToolPalette` class!

Comment: Well I took your suggestion on just removing the widgets instead of deleting, but I am still not seeing any difference.  Same two issues where the grid seems to be having problems when re-adding them on resize (they sometimes overlap each other).  Also on initial start, resize gets called an extra time.  Updated code above if you think you might know what I am doing wrong with the grid that it is misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

This might be better achieved with a `QGraphicsView`.

Create a subclass of a `QGraphicsView` that also creates a `QGraphicsScene` for itself.  Have it store the list of pixmaps you want it to display.  Override the `resizeEvent` in your subclass and have it clear the `QGraphicsScene` and re-add all the pixmaps to the scene using `QGraphicsPixmapItems`.  Before you add them to the scene, get the total width and height from the `QGraphicsView.viewport()`.  You can get the individual pixmap width/height by dividing by rows/columns.  Then scale each pixmap before you add it to the scene.

Comment: Thanks for this... while it is another avenue to pursue, I strayed away from doing this via QGraphicsScene because it seemed much more complex for just displaying some simple thumbnails.  I will use this as a backup if I can't figure out how to do this via labels and gridlayout.

Comment: If you do not like `QGraphicsView`, I'd suggest you to use `FlowLayout` demonstrated in [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html).

Its rather quite easy to implement and may suit your needs. You do not even need to specifically do anything during a resize, the layout takes care of it for you.

Comment: Found a python version here... [link]http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/examples/layouts/flowlayout.py  But unfortunately, it doesn't seem to want to cooperate if I throw this into a scollArea, which is necessary.  Just sits there without reorganizing if I resize.