# How to make a variable-column grid using PyQt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I'm trying to display an array of image thumbnails using Python and Qt4. My problem is that I don't want to calculate the amount of columns for the grid, so that when the application is resized or my thumbnails get bigger, the number of columns automatically change. 
Actually I want to use Qlabel, because images are going to have file names and possibly buttons. Is there an easy way to do it?

Something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Brendan Abel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1547004/brendan-abel)'s answer is the right and elegant way to use the power of Qt. However, if you find model-view architecture too heavy, I'd suggest you to use `FlowLayout` demonstrated in [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html).

Its rather quite easy to implement and may suit your needs.

Comment: FlowLayout worked perfectly for me. Thank you! Used this one: https://github.com/cgdougm/PyQtFlowLayout

Comment: I found this PyQt5 version works for me https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/layouts/flowlayout.py

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a `QGraphicsView`.  It's a good building block for truly custom widgets that don't really resemble any of the built-in widgets.  It uses a model/view architecture and allows you pretty much unlimited flexibility  how and where each item is drawn, as opposed to relying on the more limited `QLayout` system of placement.